# В цикле выбрать значения из двух списков так, чтобы соотношение выбранных элементов равнялось 80 к 20

Tags: алгоритм, python-3.x

Для простоты предположим, что:

- в первом списке содержатся только *числа*, а
- во втором - только *буквы*,

и есть некоторое количество итераций, на каждой из которых:

- из одного из двух списков *случайным образом* выбирается *одно значение*
- и записывается в третий список.

По завершении работы программы в этом третьем списке должны находиться и числа, и буквы в соотношении `80` к `20` (например, `80` букв и `20` чисел для цикла из `100` итераций).

Comment: При кажддой итерации проверять количество и букв, и чисел: если количество букв (чисел) равно 80 (20), то переходить к выбору только из одного списка.

Comment: Хотелось бы какое-то более универсальное решение, поскольку количество итераций может быть не равным 100, но соотношение 80% к 20% должно быть всегда постоянным.

Comment: Никто не мешает сравнивать с процентным соотношением

Comment: цикл на количество итераций делённое на 5, в цикле тянем из одной таблицы 1 раз и из другой 4 раза. алгоритм готов пишите программу )))

Comment: Не надо итераций. Используйте модуль random - там есть функция sample которая выбирает заданное количество случайных элементов из списка. Просто сначала посчитайте, сколько вам нужно элементов из первой и из второй последовательности.

Comment: если для паролей и подобных вещей хотите генерировать, то вместо `random.choice()` [лучше `secrets.choice()` использовать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html)

Comment: @Александр `random.sample()` не поможет, если вам нужно 20 цифр (`digits = '0123456789'`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы получить точное соотношение (если возможно), выбирая случайно элементы из каждой группы:

```
from string import ascii_letters, digits
import random

total = 100
nletters = round(0.8 * total)
ndigits = total - nletters
print(nletters, ndigits)  # -> 80 20

result = [random.choice(ascii_letters) for _ in range(nletters)]
result += [random.choice(digits) for _ in range(ndigits)]
```

Если точное соотношение не нужно, а вместо этого хочется просто вероятность изменить (`.8` что выпадет буква, `.2` что выпадет цифра, при этом точное соотношение букв и цифр может меняться от запуска к запуску даже при одном и том же общем числе элементов `total`), есть простое решение:

```
result = [random.choice(ascii_letters if random.random() < 0.8 else digits)
          for _ in range(total)]
```

Пример для одного из запусков:

```
>>> len(list(filter(str.isdecimal, result)))
23
```

Пример показывает, что количество цифр может отличаться от 20.

Чтобы дважды для каждого элемента в результате не вызывать random, можно распределение с весами использовать [Weighted random sample in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13047806/4279).

Answer (score 0):

Случайным образом выбираем сначала 80% из одного множества, затем оставшиеся 20% из второго, потом просто перемешиваем выбранное случайным образом...

На C++ могу набросать, на Питоне - сами...

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/204967)

Comment: мне кажется, до полноценного ответа тут не хватает болеее подробного описания алгоритма, хотя бы словами

Comment: @mymedia Что именно в описании вам непонятно? Как выбрать случайным образом значение из списка? Или как перемешать последовательность случайным образом? Это - *элементарные* действия. За описанием типа "Сгенерируйте случайное число в диапазоне от 1 до числа элементов в списке. Выберите число с данным индексом из первого списка. Перенесите его во второй список. Увеличьте счетчик количества чисел во втором списке. Если он не равен N, повторите эти действия." - то вы потеряете сам смысл алгоритма.

Answer (score 0):

Рискну предложить свой вариант решения:

```
import random

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c',  'd', 'e']
c = []
d = list(range(1, 101))
num_counter = letter_counter = 0
loop_counter = 100

for i in range(loop_counter):
    if random.choice(d) >= 21:
        c.append(random.choice(a))
        num_counter += 1
    else:
        c.append(random.choice(b))
        letter_counter += 1

print('\n', c)
print('Numbers: ', num_counter)
print('Letters: ', letter_counter)
```

Здесь очевиден один существенный недостаток: соотношение чисел к буквам лишь приблизительно составляет 80 к 20%. Если вы знаете, как это исправить - напишите об этом. Однако помимо недостатка, есть и преимущество перед предложенными выше вариантами - выполнение вообще не зависит от размеров списков a и b и типов содержащихся в них объектов.
*В любом случае, спасибо всем, кто пытался помочь с решением.*

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

random.seed()

numbers = [4, 1, 9, 2, 5, 7, 5, 8, 3]
letters = 'a c d R t G j s w'.split()
iterations = 10
perc_letters = 80

result = []
for __ in range(iterations):
    if random.random() < perc_letters / 100:
        result.append(random.choice(letters))
    else:
        result.append(random.choice(numbers))
```

`random.random()` дает случайное число от `0` до `1`.

В каждой из данного числа итераций выбираем такое случайное число и сравниваем его с данной величиной процент для букв.

С помощью функции `random.choice()` затем выбираем случайный элемент из соответствующего списка и прибавим его в результатный список.

Answer (score 0):

```
import string, random

def get_value(count, l1, l2):
    '''случайным образом выбирается одно значение'''
    for _ in range(count):
        yield random.choice(l1)
    while True:
        yield random.choice(l2)

def random_values(count1, list1, count2, list2):
    digit = get_value(count1, list1, list2)
    letter = get_value(count2, list2, list1)
    for _ in range(count1+count2):
        # из одного из двух списков случайным образом выбирается одно значение
        if random.randrange(1):
            yield next(letter)
        else:
            yield next(digit)

list_1 = list(string.digits)  # в первом списке содержатся только числа
list_2 = list(string.ascii_letters)  # во втором - только буквы
list_3 = []

# и есть некоторое количество итераций, на каждой из которых:
for val in random_values(80, list_1, 20, list_2):
    list_3.append(val)  # и записывается в третий список.
```